# Apply function doesn't result in Date format

Tags: r, date, datetime, apply

I am facing a problem when I apply an apply function on a Date column. The Date is not being displayed correctly. Need help on this

```
> head(dataF)
[1] "4-Sep-06"  "27-Oct-06" "8-Jan-07"  "28-Jan-07" "5-Jan-07"  "28-Jan-07"
> res <- apply(dataF, 2, dmy)
> head(res)
          DateM
[1,]    1157328000
[2,]    1161907200
[3,]    1168214400
[4,]    1169942400
[5,]    1167955200
[6,]    1169942400
```

Comment: What do you expect the format to look like?

Comment: Why do you need to use `apply` here in the first place?

Comment: I have other columns also (which I am going to bind to the existing data frame) on which I want to apply this function. That is the reason I chose "apply". I want the format to look like a Date object

Comment: Then you should use `lapply` instead of `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what you want to do with the output, you should not need to use `apply` or its cousins when the function `dmy` already handles vectors. Just use

```
res <- dmy(dataF)
```

Having said that, if you just want to learn how to use `apply`, Ananda's comment is correct. The following should also give you correct results.

```
res <- lapply(dataF, dmy)
```

Here is a more elaborate example where we only replace dates in a couple of columns:

```
dataF <- data.frame(x = c("4-Sep-06", "27-Oct-06", "8-Jan-07", 
                          "28-Jan-07", "5-Jan-07", "28-Jan-07"),
                    y = c("4-Jan-06", "27-Jan-06", "8-Feb-07", 
                          "28-Feb-07", "5-Mar-07", "28-Mar-07"),
                    z = c(1:6))
dataF
#           x         y z
# 1  4-Sep-06  4-Jan-06 1
# 2 27-Oct-06 27-Jan-06 2
# 3  8-Jan-07  8-Feb-07 3
# 4 28-Jan-07 28-Feb-07 4
# 5  5-Jan-07  5-Mar-07 5
# 6 28-Jan-07 28-Mar-07 6

library(lubridate)
## The third column is not a date
## Just replace the first two columns directly
dataF[1:2] <- lapply(dataF[1:2], dmy)
dataF
#            x          y z
# 1 2006-09-04 2006-01-04 1
# 2 2006-10-27 2006-01-27 2
# 3 2007-01-08 2007-02-08 3
# 4 2007-01-28 2007-02-28 4
# 5 2007-01-05 2007-03-05 5
# 6 2007-01-28 2007-03-28 6
```

Comment: Was about to post an answer with an example but just edited it into your answer instead. Hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, It is the first time I've seen such heavy editing, but I'd say you improved it, so thank you. :)

Comment: It's virtually the same answer with an example for demonstration, so I didn't think it was too heavy...

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Don't worry about it. I just meant in terms of amount of text, but I am very happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the format to look like a date object, change it to a date object.  That way, it actually **is** a date object.

```
> dataF <- c("4-Sep-06", "27-Oct-06", "8-Jan-07", 
             "28-Jan-07", "5-Jan-07",  "28-Jan-07")
> as.Date(dataF, "%d-%b-%y")
[1] "2006-09-04" "2006-10-27" "2007-01-08" "2007-01-28" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-28"
```